# Why does style attribute change p block color, but style sheet won't?

Tags: javascript, css

This is a simple question:

This code prints WELCOME in RED.

```
<p style='color:red;'>WELCOME</p>
```

When I switch to a css style sheet it prints it in BLACK

```css
p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
  color: RED;
}
```

```html
<p> WELCOME </p>
```

How come?

Every time I've tested the css style sheet version, I changed the font-size and text-align properties. And each time the browser rendered those changes but ignored color.

For example,

```css
p {
  font-size: 30pt;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
  color: GREEN;
}
```

```html
<p> WELCOME </p>
```

Rendered very large type ... but still in BLACK.

Comment: it's not the case here, check if you have more CSS involved

Comment: Are you sure that's the only CSS you have for `p` elements?

Comment: There could be several reason . Are u sure to integrate css to html,if yes are u sure to not override your style with another style code . U should check on developer console if your style is seen or not

Comment: the css is probably getting overridden , use `!important` to ignore the previous value and apply the value preceeding `!important` so something like `color: RED !important` should fix it

Comment: "!important" worked. But I can't find any reason for its need. It's a simple page. This is all I have
<body  id='body-inner-index'><div class='content-block'><div class='scroll-block'><!-- 3-column header--><div class='div-table' style='border:5px solid black;'>OTHER CLOSED DIV BLOCKS</div><p>WELCOME</div></div></body>. I mean I can't see how any of the classes used in any of the containing blocks get to override the the css style tied to <p>.  But !important works so I can't afford time to tear it apart piece by piece to find the cause. Maybe another day.